# Should Cyber Limbs be bought to each limb?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, cyberware

If I want to buy a cyber limb, it should be bought for each limb or does it come in pairs? For example, if I want both my arms to be a Cyber Limb, should I buy 2 Cyber Limbs? If so, that means that any enhancements for Cyber Limbs should be also bought for each Cyber Limb?

Answer (score 4):

The Body in Shadowrun 5 is separated into distinct zones, which can be replaced by cyberware. Whenever you replace a full zone, you also replace all contained parts, e.g. replacing an arm also replaces the hand and then incorporates it <sup>1</sup>.

- 1 left arm containing 1 lower left arm containing 1 left hand
- 1 right arm containing 1 lower right arm containint 1 right hand
- 1 left leg containing 1 lower left leg containing 1 left foot
- 1 right leg containing 1 lower right leg containing 1 right foot
- 1 torso
- 1 skull

Not exactly limbs, but closely related are the sensory organs, where the eyes are treated as separate entities but the ears are not, so add to the list:

- 2 eyes
- 1 set of ears

You can replace limbs and sensory organs partially and non-matching (e.g. get a high dexterity left hand but a high strength right arm; a left cybereye but retain the right normal eye).

Each limb or part thereof can have its own enhancements and upgrades that differ from the other limbs, e.g. you might have a left arm with a smartgun system and a right one with a grappling hand.

If you only use one limb or part thereof for a task, you use that limb's respective values for it.

Complicated rule to determine the composite values for dissimilar Limbs haven't been in since the 4th edition <sup>2</sup> and have not been introduced in the 5th edition corebook or Chrome Flesh either. The rule is in both the 4th and 5th editions to use the lowest value of all limbs taking part in the task. So if you try to push a car out of the way while having strength 6 arms, a single strength 4 leg, and a strength 2 leg, you apply the lowest value that is used within the task - in this case that is strength 2.

---

1. Shadowrun 5th Edition Core Book (2013, 2nd Printing), pp.455
2. Shadowrun 4th Edition Core Book (2005, 1st Printing), pp.335 / Shadowrun 4th Edition Anniversary Core Book (2009), p.343 ; Shadowrun 4th Edition Augmentation (2012, 3rd Printing), pp.44

Answer (score 1):

You are buying one cyber limb at a time. If you lost two arms, you buy one left arm and one right arm and modify them how ever you like. You want one high agility gunning arm and one high str arm to swing around a wave motion mace, you can do that.